# How to get current category in magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

How can i get current category in **magento2** ?

I want to get category name and category id in custom phtml file.

Comment: Most of the answers here use the `Registry` class, which is deprecated since a while. Is there a way without using `Registry`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this code. this will definitely help you.

```
<?php 
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');//get current category
    echo $category->getId();
    echo $category->getName();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Makwana Ketan

Comment: Doesn't respect dependency injection principle

Comment: Any reason for flagging my comment out ? @Makwana, you should better learn from your mistakes and share good practises (maybe fix your answer) instead of bullying people like this

Comment: I agree with @YonnTrimoreau you should follow dependency injection principles. Using object manager directly is a bad practice

Comment: Yup, it's really bad practice to use the OM directly like this. From [official Magento dev docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/object-manager.html) - Magento prohibits the direct use of the ObjectManager in your code because it hides the real dependencies of a class.

Comment: well, it will work fine. But use of objectManager in Magento is not appreciated.

Comment: Object manger should not be used here, follow DI principles

Comment: This answer really needs a clear disclaimer explaining the caveats as it's bad practice and a commonly found characteristic in stores suffering from stability and performance problems. Currently, it teaches developers bad practices, despite the all the comments below. A template should only use what the block provides, if the block does not provide it, you extend, alter, etc. the block so you can call it. I would only allow this as a fallback for critical functionality, a last resort.

Answer (score 27):

The above to seem correct, but I think that jumping straight to the Registry is not the best approach. Magento provides a Layer Resolver that already encapsulates that functionality. (See the TopMenu Block in the Catalog Plugins)

I suggest injecting the \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver class and using that to get the current category. Here is the code :

```
<?php

namespace FooBar\Demo\Block;

class Demo extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    private $layerResolver;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);

        $this->layerResolver = $layerResolver;
    }

    public function getCurrentCategory()
    {
        return $this->layerResolver->get()->getCurrentCategory();
    }
}
```

Here is what the actual *getCurrentCategory()* method does in the Resolver Class.

```
public function getCurrentCategory()
{
    $category = $this->getData('current_category');
    if ($category === null) {
        $category = $this->registry->registry('current_category');
        if ($category) {
            $this->setData('current_category', $category);
        } else {
            $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($this->getCurrentStore()->getRootCategoryId());
            $this->setData('current_category', $category);
        }
    }

    return $category;
}
```

As you can see, it does still use the registry but it provides a fallback in case that fails.

Comment: +1 for not reinventing the wheel! It isn't *exactly* what the OP asked for, but it's probably a better solution than the other answers due to the fallback mechanism. I know it was for me.

Answer (score 15):

Magento sets registry for categories being accessed. So, to get currenct category, use following method:

```
/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
 */

protected $_registry;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
) {
    $this->_registry = $registry;
}
```

and then use:

```
$category = $this->_registry->registry('current_category');//get current category
```

Now you can access the collection and fetch details such as **$category->getName()**

Comment: This is the right reply because, differently from the choosen one up above, this code respect dependency injection principle and don't use the objectManager directly within the code

Comment: I agree, it's bad practice to use the `ObjectManager` in Magento 2

Comment: Thank you @Sarfaraj

Comment: @ManishJoy The Registry is deprecated, can you suggest a new solution?

Comment: Here is an alternate to it https://www.atwix.com/magento-2/alternatives-for-deprecated-registry-class-magento-2-3/

Answer (score 11):

No need to use the object manager or inject class. You can use a built-in helper class `Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data` in the following way.

```
<?php 
    $catalogHelperData = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data');
    $categoryObject = $catalogHelperData->getCategory();
    $categoryId = $categoryObject->getId();
    $categoryName = $categoryObject->getName();
?>
```

This code snippet should work for **any phtml** (*built-in or custom*) file which is related to product listing page or product detail page.

Answer (score 0):

In *.phtml files at Category page can get Category data with following snippet:

```
$currentCategory = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data')->getCategory();
```